# For infinite dimensional vector space $V$, $V$ and $V^2$ are isomorphic

Tags: linear-algebra

How can I prove that for an infinite dimensional vector space $V$, $V$ and $V^2$ are isomorphic?

Comment: What are your thoughts?

Comment: I wanted to use less theorems as possible. I know that two vector spaces are isomorphic iff their bases have the same cardinality, and I also know that for infinite cardinal $\alpha$, $\alpha + \alpha = \alpha$, but I would like to give a straightforward proof that does not use this.

Comment: Well, it suffices just to give a bijection of bases between $V$ and $V^2$, but I can't imagine how I can do it.

Comment: I think it is going to be at least as difficult as proving that $\alpha+\alpha=\alpha$ for an infinite cardinal $\alpha$.  In fact, the two problems are very much equivalent.  You will need the Axiom of Choice to prove either statement.  If $V$ is countable-dimensional, then you can construct an explicit isomorphism $V\cong V\times V$.